# Decompressing gzipped files in Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, gzip, delphi-2009, compression

Up until Delphi 2007 I was using **DelphiZlib 0.2.99** for decompressing gzipped files. In Delphi 2009 the library does not compile anymore. Besides the conflict with Delphi's own zlib.pas unit, the code generates a number of string-related compiler errors and warnings which I don't think I can fix without a close understanding of the library code. DelphiZlib code was last modified in the year 2000, and it does not seem to have been updated since.

What can I replace it with for Delphi 2009? All I need is to decompress *.gz files. This is for a freeware project, so I strongly prefer free-with-source solutions, but I'll consider commercial libraries too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Abbrevia](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpabbrevia/)

Comment: Works great and takes under 5 minutes to figure out. Thanks, Serg!